# Select all values for given key from JSON array column

Tags: postgresql

I have a `json` array column, `foo`:

```
[{"a": "my_key_type", "b": "foo"}]
[{"a": "my_other_key_type", "b": "foo"}]
[]
[{"a": "my_key_type", "b": "bar"}, {"a": "my_other_key_type", "b": "baz"}]
```

I would like to select into an array all `a` values for each JSON element in the column. For instance:

```
['my_key_type']
['my_other_key_type']
[]
['my_key_type','my_other_key_type']
```

I was initially pursuing `json_object_keys`, but that doesn't seem to accomplish what I'm actually after, and it doesn't work on an array type. I have not found a function in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) that seems to accomplish what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this with a bit of workaround by exploding the JSON elements into rows, and then using `array_agg`:

```sql
    with keys as (
        select
            id,
            json_array_elements(my_column)->>'a' as e
        from my_table
    )
    select
        id,
        array_agg(e) as a
    from keys
    group by id;
```

This gives:

```
id | a
----------------
1  | {my_key_type}
2  | {my_other_key_type}
4  | {my_key_type,my_other_key_type}
```

Answer (score 1):

A clearer and more concise solution can be:

```
SELECT string_agg(value->>'a', ',') AS a_list
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(foo::jsonb) AS value from your_table 
) s;
```